What is the point of introducing enthalpy in biochemistry? Because biological systems are open systems?
I have good understanding of what enthalpy is.
I know that amongst the various uses of enthalpy in chemical reacting systems, there is for example the following relationship, which allows the calculation of $\Delta_{\rm r}G^\circ$ (standard free Gibbs energy of reactions) from tabulated values of $\Delta_{\rm r}H^\circ$ (standard enthalpy of reaction) and $\Delta_{\rm r}S^\circ$ (standard entropy of reaction):
$$\Delta_{\rm r}G^\circ = \Delta_{\rm r}H^\circ-T\Delta_{\rm r}S^\circ$$
However, in biochemistry textbooks, enthalpy is often introduced following those reasoning steps:

In biology, reactions occur at constant pressure.
At constant pressure, and without other work than pressure-expansion work ($-P{\rm d} V$): $dH=\delta Q_P$ (or $\Delta H=Q_P$).
$Q_P$ values can be obtained by calorimetry measurements.
(After those steps, discussions follows, stating that pressure-expansion work being often negligible, $\Delta H$ and $\Delta E$ (or $\Delta U$) values are not very different.)

At this point, it is not clear why introducing the concept of enthalpy is useful since the last argument could have been introduced right away after the writing the fist law as $\delta E = \delta Q + \delta W = \delta Q -P{\rm d}V$, to then write $\Delta E \approx Q_P$.
I suspect that there is a more profound reason why enthalpy would be useful in biochemistry but that this reason is often skipped in biochemistry textbooks due to it being too technical.
I have the "feeling" that enthalpy is useful because biochemical systems are open systems, a bit like enthalpy is useful in flow systems in chemistry, as is discussed in the answers to the question In what context is enthalpy a convenient concept? on physics.stackexchange.com.
However, biological cells are not exactly similar to 'control volumes' in flow systems for the following reasons:

Cells grow (and ultimately divide), and therefore are not strictly at steady states.
Cells select/chose the chemical species that enter and leave their 'body', and so chemical potentials $\mu_X$ must play a role; but this might then point towards using directly the Gibbs free energy $G$ rather than the enthalpy $H$.
Inflow and outflow pressures ($P_{\rm in}$ and $P_{\rm out}$) are the same, so not only pressure is constant (${\rm d}P/{\rm d}t=0$: steady-state constant) but it is uniform (contrary to situations in a chemical flow system when $P_{\rm in}≠P_{\rm out}$).

So, is there a more technical utility of introducing enthalpy in biochemistry, maybe in link with the fact that biological systems are open systems, and not only at constant (steady-state) $P$ but also at uniform $P$?
PS: References to advanced books or articles dealing with this question are welcome.

I have a feeling you thought about it too much ;)

The reasoning is really just what you outlined. Plus, lots of biochemistry books use many parameters (G, H, Keq) to describe reactions. Both Keq and G are very common (and more understandable!) for enzymatic reactions.
